# How to get the full root directory of a ContentManager in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, filepath

I was wondering if anyone here knows how to find the complete path (from the drive letter onwards) of a ContentManager instance. using this I could create a string with the right number of "..\" to append to the file path when I want to load a file from anywhere else on the computer (eg. from a registry key).

So basically I'm asking if there is a way.

Comment: See an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314327/realtime-resource-updating-in-xna

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Preferably an answer without using reflection :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just want to use [System.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) with one of [these locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx), most likely Program Files. From there, you can navigate to your application's installation directory. You could also use .Load("\MyFolder\blah") which will load from the default disk (e.g. C:\MyFolder\blah.xnb or whatever).

If you want the path of your .exe file...

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//blah blah
string GetAppDir()
{
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
}
```

Comment: I tried using "\MyFolder" but it doesn't work. I have no idea why but it throws an exception 'Could not open file', and I did copy the xnb file

Comment: The file is called MyFolder in that case :P. You'd have to use "\\MyFolder\\file" in order to load file.xnb from the folder C:\MyFolder.

Also be aware that Content.RootDirectory could be set to "\\MyFolder" and then you'd load Content from that folder normally (including sub-paths such as Textures\myTex or Sounds\powerup and so on)

Comment: I was just illustrating what I meant the actual file is Egg.xnb. What I really need is a way to get the full root directory without reflection and without setting the RootDirectory property to "\\"

Comment: Quick question: does your application have permissions to access random stuff on the C drive? If it doesn't, then that is the likely cause. It may require admin permissions/elevation (on Vista/Win 7) due to possible security hazard posed by such an application. Try loading a file from Program Files or your desktop (using System.GetFolderPath and all).

Comment: I can open a text file with a stream in C:\ so I think I have permissions

Comment: Interesting; not sure off hand without duplicating your program. Also, I amended my answer to account for my misunderstanding of your question.

Comment: Ah, that was exactly what I wanted. Now I can combine that path with my content RootDirectory and then use that. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh wait, that class `Application` is in `System.Windows.Forms` but I'm using XNA.

Comment: You can still use it; just add the appropriate reference to your project. XNA depends on WF internally, so it's not like you're actually introducing new dependencies.

Comment: I fixed it by adding the reference and NOT using the namespace because it clashes with a class in the XNA Framework. I used:  using TApplication = System.Windows.Forms.Application;